# mvvm-light RaisePropertyChanged messenger not broadcasted

Tags: mvvm-light

I cant seem to get this working properly.

I've got two ViewModels. VM1 registers a message with the following code

```
Messenger.Default.Register<PropertyChangedMessage<int>>(
    this,
    (action) => DispatcherHelper.CheckBeginInvokeOnUI(() => UpdateOverlayIcon(action.NewValue))
);
```

VM2 fires the RaisePropertyChanged when property is being set.

```
// Update bindings and broadcast change using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Messenging
RaisePropertyChanged(UnreadTweetsPropertyName, oldValue, value, true);
```

Now, shouldn't the VM1.UpdateOverlayIcon() method run right after the RaisePropertyChanged is fired in VM2? Or have i missed an essential part of this, because it doesn't work for me? I have been struggling with this all day long and tried a number of different methods.

Answer (score 2):

This should work quite easily - just make sure that the Message Register code is being registered before the RaisePropertyChanged notification is called.

The other thing to check is that your types match - so you are listening for a Message with INT - is this the type of UnreadTweetsPropertyName? (it wont receive it if they dont match).

The problem with this approach is that ANY int property that is broadcasting will be received... I would like to be able to pass in a token so that I can match them up...